# JQuery and getelementbyid fail, NOT a timing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Had to delete my previous post because I didn't post the JS sample. I've fixed it now:

I have an ajax call that returns a new comment (long after the page is loaded so I know the target element is properly in the DOM) and will append it to my list (under "wli_5_comments .comments" using jquery's append routine). The problem is that I can't access the "wli_5_comments" element for some reason. Jquery doesn't think it exists and getelementbyid fails too.

For example, if I use document.getelementbyid(someid).innerHTML it tells me "can't get html of undefined" or something. Alerting any properties in that or jquery results in the same thing: undefined... doesn't exist, even though I can see it right there in my document inspector. The id is identical, the quotes are fine, all the tags are closed properly. WTH?

```
<div id="wli_5_commments" class="wli_comments_area hide" style="display: block;">
<h2 class="hdr">Comments</h2>
    <div class="comments">

        <div id="wlc_21" class="wli_comment" userid="9">
            <div class="msg">adfsgfhgsf</div>
            <div class="name_area">
                <div class="name"><div>someuser</div>
                <div class="date">(2014-04-12)</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="buttons"><img class="delete_button" src="http://localhost:80/graphics/red_x_off.png" pop="Delete this comment"></div>



        </div>      
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Here's my test code which fails at every step (other than the first alert which results in "wli_5_comments" as expected):

```
                    alert('wli_'+wli_key+'_comments');
                alert(document.getElementById('wli_'+wli_key+'_comments').innerHTML);
                alert('#wli_'+wli_key+'_comments'+$('#wli_'+wli_key+'_comments').attr('id'));
                console.log($('#wli_'+wli_key+'_comments').find('.comments').html());
                $('#wli_'+wli_key+'_comments .comments').append(msg['result']);
```

Also note that not only is the JS called in a "document.ready" block, but in an AJAX callback that is ONLY triggered after user interaction. There's no way this is related to calling an element that doesn't exist yet (like all the other answers that StackOverflow thinks my question is a duplicate of).

Comment: should be `document.getElementById('wli_'+wli_key+'_comments').innerHTML` instead of `document.getElementById('wli_'+wli_key+'_comments').innerHTML()`.

Comment: are you using jquery's `ready()`??

Comment: paste your complete js code

Comment: Or you can provide the relative code into jsfiddle.

Comment: With developer tools open in your browser, are any errors being logged when the `alert` code executes? If so, can you post them please.

Comment: There are no errors. I check the console for the information I logged with the JS command above, but it doesn't work. The third line where I alert the resulting string (wli_5_comments) and then the id of that element (which should return wli_5_comments also) alerts this: "wli_5_comments undefined".

Comment: My code is 1900 lines long on just this page (not counting includes) so I don't think it would be helpful to list everything here. I've done functions similar to this one repeatedly on this page and others and they work fine. I don't know what's special about this one.

Answer (score 0):

Bah. I finally solved it by doing a copy of the ID from my console display to my alerted code. When I did, I noticed that "commments" and "comments" aren't the same word (there's an extra "m" in there).

Thanks all :)